# Is there any way to fit multiple files in one Talend Open Studio project without running out of memory?

Tags: java, ms-access, out-of-memory, etl, talend

I have to use two Access files (the first is an **accdb** and the second an **mdb** file) which contain multiple tables as the source (tAccessInput) and integrate the data in Microsoft SQL Server.
The issue is, that after placing the first 4 input tables, I run out of memory.
I tried to allocate more memory to the system by altering the JVM parameters but the problem still persists. What else could I try? Have you faced any similar problem?

Comment: I have face out of memory issue even with excel file. However setting EventMode in tExcelInputFile component resolved that issue. But EventMode also introduce problem related to date type.

Comment: Can you try to loop over Access files with SQL limit in order to limit the number of rows in each iteration? Looping over database results with SQL limit and ``Loop```is a common way to reduce the memory consumption.